# (Mapbox) When rendering tileset with lines, sometimes many of the points in the tileset are ignored, resulting in jagged lines

Tags: mapbox

I am making a tileset with historical US state boundaries, and then I render them in my style. Most frustratingly, in MapBox Studio, the rendered lines are very often drawn as if many of the points in the tileset are ignored -- they appear grossly simplified.  Sometimes when I view the style they appear fine; sometimes not. The behavior is unpredictable.

At this very moment, this problem is occurring only at certain zoom levels. Note that these zoom levels do not seem to correspond to the zoom levels at which the tileset is made to work (namely, 0 thru 10).

Screenshots:
- [Incorrectly rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLyEM.png)
- [Correctly rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Eo2.png)

Here's the tippecanoe I used to make the tileset:

`tippecanoe -o states.mbtiles -f -z 10 -Z 0 -B 0 -pS -pp --read-parallel -l states -n states states.geojson`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [simplification section](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/uploads/#simplification) of this [uploading data to Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/uploads/#simplification) troubleshooting guide, this is result of simplification. Your tippecanoe command uses `-pS`, which corresponds to "don't simplify lines and polygons at maxzoom (but do simplify at lower zooms)", as noted in the documentation [here](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#line-and-polygon-simplification). You might instead consider using `-ps`, which will prevent simplification of lines and polygons at all zoom levels.

When you say "note that these zoom levels do not seem to correspond to the zoom levels at which the tileset is made to work," it sounds like it might be the case that the oversimplification is occurring at zoom levels greater than 10. You also mentioned that "sometimes" they appear fine. If by this you mean that at a fixed zoom level, the lines are sometimes rendered correctly but other times at the same zoom level the lines are oversimplified, I would recommend writing in to [Mapbox Support](https://support.mapbox.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000291231) sharing the specific style ID so that we can take a closer look.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just tried `-ps`, and the result is that the lines are simplified in all zoom levels.

The simplification happening at zoom levels between 0 and 10.

What I meant by "sometimes" is that this happens unpredictably. Eg, when testing `-ps` just now, I opened my style in Studio (with the lines appearing simplified), then clicked on the layer that draws the lines. Under "Select data" there was an error msg saying that the selected data couldn't be found (which makes no sense since it is displaying this data!). I reselected the data, and now the lines appear correctly!

Comment: I don't even know what to ask at this point. The behavior of Studio is just too bizarre and unpredictable for me to describe what's happening. I took a video and will send it to the support email address.